# Vocal Assistant app replacing Google Assistant in react native (preferably) or in Java

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm actually making a vocal assistant, and I would like to make an application for it, that would replace Google Assistant on my phone. In the Android Settings, it's theorically possible to use another app instead of Google Assistant. My question is:

Is there a particular way to code my application so that it could replace Google Assistant ? And is it possible in React Native or must I do it in Java ?